# Solving recurrence relations with negative powers or reciprocals

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

What are the methods that can be used to solve recurrence relations such as,

- $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$  ,
- $a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{1}{a_n}$ ,

and reduce $a_n$ to a closed-form formula? And are there any general ways to solve this for arbitrary negative powers like $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_n^{-k}$ ?

Comment: something related was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279057/difficult-recurrence-problem) some hours ago but didn't have much tracking, and there is a look at the asymptotics of this sequence [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542068/asymptotic-behavior-of-x-n1-x-n-frac1x-n-space-space-space-x-0-1) and a try to a closed formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/closed-form-for-the-sequence-defined-by-a-0-1-and-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the first one
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\qquad \text{with} \qquad a_1=1$$ have a look [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C29%2C941&sort=&language=&go=Search).

No closed form (neither asymptotics).

Comment: Although, there are asymptotics to this sequence as shown in the comments